# What are some non-expletives interjections for "I almost forgot [something]"

Tags: interjections

Just before leaving a conversation with someone, what non-expletives interjection could I use instead of the sentence "I almost forgot ..." if I want to sound apologetic?

For instance:

> Could you please move my car from the entrance?... I almost forgot, you'll be needing my keys.

Comment: *and* seems sufficient?

Comment: Hell, that's what expletives are for. Heck, there's the infinite euphemisms that substitute. And the ever present vaguefiers *Oh*, *Oy*, *Ooh*, *Oops*, *Hey*, *Um*, *My-my*, and *Well*,

Comment: @k1eran I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I was half-joking but to be serious I think depending on your intonation and pauses  *and* actually works. *Could you please move my car from the entrance ? **... And** here are the keys.*

Comment: @k1eran I've edited the answer to clarify the intention of the speaker.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I've edited the question to exclude expletives, since those could be used pretty much for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about "Oh, right"? Or some variant of it

> Could you please move my car from the entrance?
>
> > ... **Oh, right**, here are the keys.
> >     ... **Right, and**, here are the keys.
> >     ... **Right, of course,** here are the keys.

You could also try changing your sentence just a bit to allow for more expression:

> Could you please move my car from the entrance?
>
> > ... **Right, you'll be needing my keys, won't you? My apologies.**

Comment: Do you know how is it spelled the one that sound like "Ups!" without the /ps/ sound, just /u/?

Comment: Never mind, "Ooh!" was what I was looking for. There is an audio clip [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ooh#Interjection).